# Razorpay integration in angular "serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker, razorpay

I have integrated razorpay in angular project when i call payment option i got some issue in console.

The error message is

```
"serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest.
```

I have initially added pwa. It has added some files and changes

> ng add @angular/pwa

my main.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";  
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

if (environment.production) {
 enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 imports: [
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
 ],
```

how do i fix this issue **"serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest**